# Extracting Text from a Cell with colon

Tags: excel, vba

using VBA in Text "ABC : DEF : GHK :XYZ " I need to extract text after last colon i.e "XYZ" there may be one or two or many more colon in text

Comment: You can use `Split` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function

Comment: Just letting you know it's possible within Excel itself too using formulae. No need for VBA or UDF.

Answer (score 0):

Find the last `:` with `InStrRev()` then just read from that point to the end.

```
result = mid$(the_string, InStrRev(the_string, ":") + 1, len(the_string))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Split()` function, you can do the following. I prefer to store the return array of the split in an array variable, as could use this further down the line etc.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Split_Function()
    
    Dim sText As String
    Dim aSplit As Variant
    
    sText = ActiveCell.Value
    
    aSplit = Split(sText, ":")
    
    Debug.Print aSplit(UBound(aSplit))
    
End Sub
```